# No commands registered in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to build a new custom command in Laravel 5 like so:

```
php artisan make:console Tenant --command=tenant:do
```

And it created the class in App\Console\Commands like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Tenant extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'tenant:do';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Run commands for all tenants.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

But now when I try to run this command with `php artisan tenant:do`, it return with an error saying:

> [InvalidArgumentException] There are
>   no commands defined in the "tenant" namespace.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you add your command to `app/Console/Kernel.php`, as outlined in the docs here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#registering-commands

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\Tenant'
];
```

Comment: Stupid mistake. *facepalm* Thank you for helping me out. :)

Comment: np, glad I could assist. please accept the answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't do it back then. It was telling me to wait for another while. :)